# Adjust how comments work in markdown-mode

Tags: comment, markdown, markdown-mode

How can I adjust how `M-;` (`comment-dwim`) works in `markdown-mode`? Specifically, I'd like for it to not use delimiters for each line. As an example, in Markdown mode, if I commend a line like

```
This is a comment
that spans multiple lines
```

I get

```
<!-- This is a comment -->
<!-- that spans multiple lines -->
```

But I would prefer for it to look like

```
<!---
This is a comment
that spans multiple lines
--->
```

(web-mode does something similar to this, but also insists on indenting the comment, which seems unnecessary)

Answer (score 1):

As a first approximation, try this:

```el
(defun ndk/md-set-comment-stuff ()
   (setq-local comment-style 'extra-line)
   (setq-local comment-continue "")
   (setq-local comment-start "<!--")
   (setq-local comment-end "-->"))

(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook #'ndk/md-set-comment-stuff)
```

You have to close and reopen the file after evaluating the above code.

It *almost* does what you want, but not quite. The result on the above is:

```md
<!--
This is a comment
that spans multiple lines
  -->
```

The extra spaces are produced by `comment-make-extra-lines`: it sets the variable `eindent` to 2 in a section of the code that has the following comment above it:

```
;; Try to match CS and CE's content so they align aesthetically.
```

It seems to me that it fails to do that: I haven't looked at the algorithm in detail but it seems to align the dashes vertically. In any case, the value of `eindent` is used later on to add the two spaces to the left of the closing delimiter. Unfortunately, I see no obvious way of changing that behavior (other than changing the code of course, but that's a can of worms that I don't want to get into).

Comment: I'd also be happy with the `<!--` on the same line as the comment if that ends up being easier to do.

Comment: I don't think it's any easier.